# setting object variables inside function

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11

I've been trying to set variables for a class inside a outside function; I think that this ends up erasing the class after the function exits, if this is true, what are ways around it?

```
Book bookArray[lineIndex];    
bookArray[0].setTitle("Here!");

//function in loop called in main
for (int i = 0; i<lineIndex; i++)
{
    arrayToBook(tempArray, bookArray[i]);
}

cout << bookArray[0].getTitle() << endl;
//returns empty space

//function definition
void arrayToBook(string* tempArray, Book bookIn)
{
    bookIn.setTitle(tempArray[0]);
    bookIn.setAuthor(tempArray[1]);
    //other sets
}
```

Comment: Try passing your `bookIn` as a reference, like this: `void arrayToBook(string* tempArray, Book& bookIn)`

Comment: The object, at the end of the execution of the function, is destroied if you pass it bye value, as in you example (`Book bookIn`); but you can pass it by reference (`Book & bookIn`) to avoid the copy and to modify the object passed (`bookArray[i]`)

Comment: You are passing `Book` by value, hence it is copied, and all the modifications are being done to the copy (instead of an original object), and that copy is destroyed after function exits. Consider passing it by reference. Also, provide [mcve], since the code snippet that you are showing is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As state in comment, you should pass argument by (non const) reference:

```
void arrayToBook(const string* tempArray, Book& bookIn)
{
    bookIn.setTitle(tempArray[0]);
    bookIn.setAuthor(tempArray[1]);
    //other sets
}
```

else you modify only a fresh copy.